# Como detectar quais são os pontos em comum entre duas circunferências?

Tags: c, matemática, geometria

Preciso de auxilio para o seguinte programa:

Receber do teclado as equações de duas circunferências:

```
c1= X^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0
c2= X^2+y^2+a2=x+by+c=0
```

e mostrar se as circunferências tem pontos em comuns, interseções.

Sou estudante de engenharia química, não entendo quase nada de programação (não é minha área), diante disso se alguém puder me dar uma "luz".

Comment: Você pelos menos entende qual é a lógica matemática que deverá ser implementada? Isto é, sabe como identificar os pontos comuns de duas funções?

Comment: Basicamente, vc irá igualar as funções, desenvolver os sistema descobrindo o x ou y, deste modo jogando o mesmo na função original, matémática simples, como descrito no exemplo a seguir: https://pir2.forumeiros.com/t36587-intersecao-de-circunferencias                                .Porém, minha dificuldade é transcrever isso para a linguagem c.

Comment: O ideal primeiro é saber classificar se essas circunferências se encontram... pode ser que elas não se encontrem jamais no plano real, pode ser que elas apenas toquem tangencialmente uma na outra, etc

Comment: Matheus, está esclarecido? Ou precisa de uma resposta mais objetiva?

Comment: Brigado ai Galera, consegui  já resolver aqui.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema aqui é clássico da Geometria Analítica, onde você dá um jeito de tratar de geometria sem usar compassos nem réguas. Se difere muito da geometria clássica porque você representa a Geometria através da Álgebra, única e exclusivamente Álgebra.

## Definindo uma circunferência

Uma circunferência é o conjunto de pontos equidistantes a um ponto fixo; esse ponto fixo é o **centro** da circunferência e a distância é o seu **raio**. Isso permite que você desenhe circunferências de 1 dimensão até N dimensões. No caso, o interesse especial é com 2 dimensões, o plano cartesiano.

Você precisa de três informações para saber se um ponto pertence a uma circunferência em específico (além, claro, do ponto em questão):

- o centro da circunferência
- o raio da circunferência
- como se calcula a distância entre dois pontos quaisquer

A fórmula a seguir condensa essas informações todas em uma única equação:

```
(p.x - c.x)^2 + (p.y - c.y)^2 - r^2 = 0
```

Que pode ser expandida na seguinte forma:

```
p.x^2 + p.y^2 - 2*c.x *p.x - 2*c.y*p.y + c.x^2 + c.y^2 - r^2 = 0
```

Como o centro `c` é uma coordenada no plano, ela é uma constante na equação. Portanto, `c.x` e `c.y` também são. O mesmo vale para o raio `r`. Então, vou representar `c.x^2 + c.y^2 - r^2` com a constante arbitrária `K`. As constantes que multiplicam `p.x` e `p.y` vão ser substituídas por `mx` e `my`. Essa então é a forma final da equação:

```
p.x^2 + p.y^2 - mx*p.x - my*p.y + K = 0
```

Anteriormente eu disse que precisa de dois fatores, mas nessa ultima equação aparecem apenas os termos do centro e do raio (compensados e escondidos atrás de constantes). Mas onde entra o terceiro elemento necessário?, aquele que diz que é necessário saber como se calcula a distância entre dois pontos arbitrários?

Entra na forma geral da fórmula. Se você reparar, a distância em um plano cartesiano segue o Teorema de Pitágoras. Exemplo clássico de geometria clássica. Mas podemos definir outros valores para calcular distância. Com isso, obtemos também formas bem peculiares de "circunferências" para cada "geometria" nova, baseada nessa ideia de distância (veja [esse vídeo do Infinite Series](https://youtu.be/ineO1tIyPfM) para mais detalhes).

E se a distância fosse dada pela fórmula da distância Manhattan? Então o círculo obedeceria a seguinte equação:

```
|p.x - c.x| + |p.y - c.y| - r = 0
```

Posso assumir de maneira segura que seu problema se dá em circunferências que seguem uma geometria em que as distâncias são calculadas de modo bem tradicional, pois caso contrário estaria **muito** explícito que esse não é o caso.

## Classificação de posição relativa de duas circunferências

Existem algumas posições possíveis que duas circunferências podem estar em relação a outra. E essas posições possíveis dependem do tamanho relativo do raio dessas duas circunferências.

Para comparar o raio, só temos duas possibilidades:

- o raio das duas é distinto, situação na qual a de menor raio será a circunferência `o1` e a maior `o2`
- o raio das duas é do mesmo tamanho

É possível sempre assumir no primeiro caso que `o2` será a circunferência com maior raio. Isso não reduz em nada a generalização do que for encontrado.

Vamos assumir aqui que `o2` tem o centro coincidente com o centro de nosso sistema de coordenadas e que `o1` não possa se movimentar no eixo Y, ficando presa ao eixo X. Não só ao eixo X, mas com `o1.c.x >= 0`. Nas primeiras seções vou discorrer sobre os possíveis posicionamentos relativos, para então (e apenas então) demonstrar que assumir essas restrições não implica em perda de generalidade, que na verdade todas as outras variações são apenas formas simétricas desse caso base:

### Posicionamento relativo com raios diferentes

No começo, `o1.c = o2.c`, então as duas circunferências estão centradas na origem. Nesse caso, elas não irão se tocar. O posicionamento delas é "não-secante interior".

Posso mover `o1` até antes da posição `o1.c.x + o1.r < o2.r` que a posição relativa continuará a mesma. Esse intervalo é:

```
0 <= o1.c.x < o2.r - o1.r
```

No momento em que `o1.c.x + o1.r = o2.r`, as duas circunferências serão "tangentes internas".

Se eu for um pouco além do tangencialmente interno, então eu terei que as circunferências serão "secantes" uma com a outra. Isso significa que o encontro entre elas é uma secção (daí o nome "secante"). Esse intervalo é dado por:

```
o2.r - o1.r < o1.c.x < o2.r + o1.r
```

Não há distinção entre classificação de secantes.

Ao chegar no limite desse intervalo (mas ainda dentro dele), as duas circunferências mal estarão em contato uma com a outra. Quando a distância dos centros das circunferências for a soma dos raios, terei extrapolado esse intervalo e elas serão apenas "tangentes externas". A fórmula é:

```
o1.c.x = o1.r + o2.r
```

Qualquer coisa além disso, elas se tornam "não-secantes externas", onde elas não se tocam mais:

```
o1.c.x > o1.r + o2.r
```

Recapitulando:

- não-secante interna
  distância dos centros menor do que a diferença de raios
  `d < r2 - r1`
- tangente interna
  distância entre os centros igual a diferença entre os raios
  `d = r2 - r1`
- secante
  distância entre os centros maior do que a diferença entre os raios, mas menor do que a soma
  `r2 - r1 < d < r2 + r1`
- tangente externa
  distância entre os centros igual a soma dos raios
  `d = r2 + r2`
- não-secantes externas
  distância entre os centros maior do que a soma dos raios
  `r2 + r1 < d`

O gif abaixo sumariza esses 5 tipos:

[image: desenho automatizado da reta obtida a partir da "subtração" da equação de duas circunferências]

### Posicionamento relativo com raios idênticos

Nesse caso, o começo com `o1.c.x = 0` produzirá a mesma circunferência que `o2`. Então elas são circunferências "sobrepostas".

Depois disso, até que a distância seja duas vezes o raio (ou a soma dos raios, como no caso de raios diferentes), elas serão secantes:

```
o1.c.x < o1.r*2
```

Ao alcançar o dobro do raio, elas serão tangentes externas:

```
o1.c.x = o1.r*2
```

Além disso, elas serão não-secantes:

```
o1.c.x > o1.r*2
```

Recapitulando:

- sobrepostas
  distância dos centros nula
  `d = 0`
- secantes
  distância dos centros
  `0 < d < 2*r`
- tangentes externas
  distância dos centros igual a duas vezes o raio
  `d = 2*r`
- não secantes
  distância dos centros além de dois raios
  `d > 2*r`

### Prova de simetria

Os nomes `o1` e `o2` não são inerentes aos objetos de estudo, então eu posso colocar qualquer rótulo em qualquer objeto sem descaracterizá-lo. Logo, eu posso definir meu sistema de rotularização sem perder generalidade.

Sobre o caso em que `o2` não estar no centro. Eu posso fazer a translação de todos os objetos no plano até que `o2.c = (0,0)`. Como estou fazendo a translação de todos os objetos ao mesmo tempo, eles mantêm suas posições relativas uns com os outros. Então, a operação de translação do plano continua não interferindo na generalidade da solução.

Agora, imagine que `o1` não esteja exatamente no eixo X. Mas sim deslocada 47º no sentido anti-horário. Se eu rotacionar o plano 47º no sentido horário, o centro de `o1` passaria a ser no novo eixo X. E como a rotação foi feita no plano, as propriedades se mantiveram.

Com isso, podemos ver que os casos acima, em que as seguintes verdades acontecem:

```
o1.r <= o2.r
o2.c = (0,0)
o1.c = (x, 0) | x >= 0
```

classificam todos os infinitos casos possíveis de posicionamento relativo de duas circunferências.

## Verificando se uma fórmula dada é uma circunferência

Se você tiver a garantia de que os dados passados são dados controlados, tudo bem. Agora, e se forem dados selvagens? Dados que não foram normalizados? Dados fornecidos por pessoas que podem digitar erroneamente?

Para isso, devemos nos preocupar se os dados fazem sentido. Talvez para a pergunta em específico não seja o caso de se preocupar com isso. Mas alguém pode precisar saber disso, e também é divertido verificar.

Para uma circunferência ser válida, no caso de distâncias dadas pelo Teorema de Pitágoras, ela pode aceitar qualquer centro, porém o raio deve ser não negativo. Caso o raio seja 0, a circunferência é apenas um ponto no plano. Tem quem considere isso uma circunferência, tem quem ache que não é, mas por simplicidade podemos considerar que é.

Vamos pegar a fórmula novamente. Como o único parâmetro fornecido é `p`, podemos ignorar ele e por diretamente seus campos:

```
x^2 + y^2 - mx*x - my*y + K = 0
```

Devido ao modo como criamos `mx`, sabemos que, nessa fórmula, o valor de `c.x = mx/2`. O mesmo vale para `c.y`.

Então, para descobrir se o valor é válido, precisamos substituir em `K` esses valores e encontrar `r^2`:

```
K = c.x^2 + c.y^2 - r^2
```

Multiplicando por `4` dos dois lados:

```
4*K = 4*c.x^2 * 4*c.y^2 - 4*r^2 = mx^2 + my^2 - 4*r^2
```

Portanto, isolando `4*r^2`:

```
4*r^2 = mx^2 + my^2 - 4*K
```

Para `r` assumir um valor real, temos que isso tudo deva ser não negativo:

```
mx^2 + my^2 - 4*K >= 0
```

Caso isso não seja verdade, ou a forma tratado não é um círculo, ou é um círculo com raio imaginário (não sei qual a interpretação geométrica para isso, mas é o que de fato ele seria).

### Outras verificações

Está implícito no problema que a forma dada é sempre com o fator que multiplica `x^2` e o fator que multiplica `y^2` é 1. Esse valor pode ser qualquer valor arbitrário, desde que seja o mesmo para `x^2` e `y^2`.

Pegue a equação:

```
x^2 + y^2 - mx*x - my*y + K = 0
```

Multiplique por `a` dos dois lados:

```
a*x^2 + a*y^2 - a*mx*x - a*my*y + a*K = 0
```

Continua descrevendo uma circunferência.

## Achando a interseção

Dadas duas fórmulas distintas de circunferências, podemos primeiramente verificar em que situação elas se encaixam. Podemos verificar se os raios são ou não os mesmos e, assim, determinar se elas são tangentes, secantes ou não-secantes de acordo com a distância de seus centros. Só com isso, então, já saberemos quantas soluções esperar. As possibilidades são:

- infinitas (concêntricas e de mesmo raio)
- 2 (secante)
- 1 (tangente, externa ou interna)
- 0 (não-secantes, externa ou interna)

Se, algebricamente, subtrairmos as duas equações de circunferências fornecidas, obteremos o seguinte:

```
x^2 + y^2 - mx1*x - my1*y + K1 = 0      -
x^2 + y^2 - mx2*x - my2*y + K2 = 0
_________________________________________

x^2 - x^2 + y^2 - y^2 - mx1*x + mx2*x - my1*y + my2*y + K1 - K2 = 0 - 0

x*(mx2 - mx1) + y*(my2 - my1) + K1 - K2 = 0
```

Isso é uma reta. Eu particularmente não sei o que é esse reta, o que ela representa, mas eu sei que é uma reta. Se por acaso `my1 = my2`, então eu sei que a validade dessa equação independe de  `y`, portanto ela é uma reta vertical. Nesse caso, eu posso obter o valor de `x`. O mesmo vale para o índice de `x`, com `mx1 = mx2` tendo uma reta horizontal.

Bem, no parágrafo anterior eu disse que não sabia o que era essa reta, correto? Bem, parcialmente apenas. Eu consigo obter os mesmos resultados quando eu faço com que a equação 1 seja igual a equação 2. Passar a equação 2 para o outro lado, de modo que fique apenas o 0 do lado direito da equação, equivale a fazer essa subtração. Então, essa reta obtida por essa "subtração algébrica" das fórmulas é, para o caso de secantes e tangentes, a reta que encosta nos pontos comuns das duas circunferências. No caso da tangente, é uma reta tangente a ambas as circunferências, no caso das secantes, é uma reta secante.

Para o caso de não-secantes? Não sei. Esse segmento é perpendicular ao segmento que une os dois centros. Não achei nenhuma relação específica sobre a razão na qual divide esse segmento.

O que eu de fato tenho é que eu conheço essa reta e também sei quantas interseções existem entre `o1` e `o2`. A partir dessa reta, consigo diminuir em 1 o grau de liberdade do sistema (portanto voltando para 1), seja achando uma constante para uma das variáveis (casos de retas horizontais/verticais), seja pondo `y` em função de `x`. Aplicando essa redução dos graus de liberdade, substituindo o valor obtido na equação referente a `o1`, obteremos os valores de `y` (ou de `x` no caso de reta horizontal) através da equação de segundo grau. Esses pontos interceptam ao mesmo tempo as duas circunferências.

Você pode ver que, quando há interseção, a reta obtida sempre passa na interseção. Para o caso de não-secantes internas a interpretação do que significa essa reta é algo estranho (não foi representado para concêntricas porque essa reta estaria no infinito em todas as direções):

[image: desenho automatizado da reta obtida a partir da "subtração" da equação de duas circunferências]

### Caso de reta inclinada

Esse é o caso mais genérico. Com isso, obtenho uma função de `y` dado `x`:

```
y = - x*(mx2 - mx1) - K1 + K2
    --------------------------
           my2 - my1
```

Como são todas constantes conhecidas, posso simplificar para:

```
y = -a*x + b
```

Então, substituindo o valor de `y` em qualquer uma das circunferências, obtemos uma equação do segundo grau que depende apenas de `x`:

```
x^2 + (-a*x + b)^2 - mx1*x - (-a*x + b)*x + K1 = 0
```

Álgebra, álgebra, álgebra:

```
(1 + a^2 + a)*x^2 + (-2*a*b - mx1 - b)*x + K1 + b^2 = 0
```

Com isso, podemos aplicar a solução de Bhaskara e achar as duas ou uma raiz dessa equação. Para obter a interseção então, basta obter os valores de `y` para os `x` encontrados.

### Caso da reta horizontal

Quando a reta é horizontal, temos que:

```
y*(my2 - my1) = K2 - K1
```

Portanto obtemos o valor de `y`:

```
y =  K2 - K2
    ---------
    my2 - my1
```

Então obtemos um valor constante para `y`. Substituímos na equação de uma das circunferências e obtemos uma equação do segundo grau em `x`. Bhaskara de novo.

### Caso da reta vertical

Idêntico ao anterior, porém o valor constante encontrado é `x` e devemos resolver Bhaskara para `y`.

## Recapitulando

É possível determinar, nessa ordem:

1. Classificar se as formas quádricas fornecidas são circunferências ou não
2. Determinar quantos pontos de interseção há entre as circunferências
3. Se for secante ou tangente, quais os pontos de interseção dessas circunferências

Através dos índices da fórmula, temos uma inequação mágica que garante isso:

```
mx^2 + my^2 - 4*K >= 0
```

A identificação da quantidade de interseções (que varia entre os valores `{ 0, 1, 2, infinito }`) define  se vamos tentar encontrar essas interseções ou não. Identificamos quantas interseções tem de acordo com o posicionamento relativo entre as duas circunferências. Porém, a nossa definição de posicionamento relativo depende de encontrar os seguintes construtos das circunferências:

1. Seu centro
2. Seu raio

O centro é fácil obter:

```
c = (mx/2 ; my/2)
```

Já o raio é dado por:

```
r = (c.x^2 + c.y^2 - K)^0.5
```

Com essas quatro informações nas mãos, primeiro verificamos se os raios são do mesmo tamanho ou não. Se for de tamanhos diferentes, então já sabemos que não existe a interseção de infinitos pontos, porém devemos nos preocupar em classificar se uma circunferência vai ser interna a outra sem tocar ou só tocando tangencialmente. Esses casos são dados por (seja `d` a distância entre os centros):

- não-secante interna
  `d < r2 - r1`
- tangente interna
  `d = r2 - r1`
- secante
  `r2 - r1 < d < r2 + r1`
- tangente externa
  `d = r2 + r1`
- não-secante externa
- `r2 + r1 < d`

Quando as circunferências tem o mesmo raio, a possibilidade de ser encontro em todos os infinitos pontos é com `d = 0`. Qualquer valor de distância maior do que isso até o valor de tangente externa implica em secante: `0 < d < 2*r`, mas também pode ser reescrito como `r2 - r1 < d < r2 + r1`. Portanto, o único caso especial é com infinitos pontos de interseção, distância zero. Todos os outros são idênticos aos fornecidos pelas inequações acima.

Sabendo se há interseção ou não, se for um número finito de interseções, podemos tentar encontrar os pontos dessa interseção.

Encontramos isso partindo da seguinte equação:

```
x*(mx2 - mx1) + y*(my2 - my1) + K1 - K2 = 0
```

Com isso, podemos obter `y` para um valor de `x`, ou então um valor constante para `x` , ou então um valor constante para `y`. Substituímos o que encontramos na equação de um dos círculos gerando uma equação do segundo grau e, então, obtemos o valor/os valores para uma das variáveis. Se for o caso de termos `y` em função de `x`, precisamos então encontrar quais seriam esses `y`s.

> mais tarde eu coloco a resolução programática

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilio meu amigo, já me deu uma excelente ajuda de como devo montar a estrutura do código.

Comment: Mas se vc conseguir postar a resolução programática para q eu possa ver , seria de grande valia.

Comment: @MatheusNunes estou incrementando a resposta. Com o tempo, chegarei nela. Peço paciência ^^ Só postei o estado atual dela (e o anterior) porque creio que já ajudaria muita gente