# Como desenhar uma reta usando geometria de tartaruga?

Tags: python, geometria

Estou tentando complementar minha resposta a uma [pergunta sobre interseções de circunferências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260057/64969). Nessa resposta, em dado momento, eu obtenho uma equação da reta na através dos coeficientes `a,b,c`:

```
r: a*x + b*y + c = 0
```

Gostaria de representar essa reta na tela usando tartaruga ([`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle)), de preferência usando apenas [geometria de tartaruga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics):

- baixar/subir a caneta
- virar-se para esquerda/direita `R` graus
- andar `S` passos para frente

No caso, minha tartaruga começa da origem, virada para o sentido positivo do eixo X (virada para eixo X+).

É adequado também retornar ao local de origem da tartaruga após um procedimento de desenho. Após desenhar algo, ficar em uma posição aleatória não me é positivo.

## O que tenho

Dependendo da inclinação da reta, eu tenho uma estratégia diferente de como desenhá-la.

### Reta horizontal

Representando a reta apenas por `(a,b,c)`, se `a == 0`, então temos uma reta horizontal, com `y = -c/b`.

Desse modo, preciso fazer o seguinte:

```
subir caneta
virar 90° para a esquerda     # fico virado para o eixo Y+
andar -c/b
virar 90° para a direita      # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
baixar caneta
desenha a reta                # voltando ao ponto de partida da reta
subir caneta
virar 90° para a direita      # fico virado para o eixo Y-
andar -c/b                    # retorna para a origem
virar 90° para a esquerda     # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
```

Em Python, sendo `t` a tartaruga:

```
t.penup()
t.left(90)           # fico virado para o eixo Y+
t.forward(-c/b)
t.right(90)          # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
t.pendown()
# desenha a reta e volta a esse mesmo ponto
t.penup()
t.right(90)          # fico virado para o eixo Y-
t.forward(-c/b)      # retorna para a origem
t.left(90)           # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
```

### Reta vertical

Representando a reta apenas por `(a,b,c)`, se `b == 0`, então temos uma reta vertical, com `x = -c/a`.

Desse modo, preciso fazer o seguinte:

```
subir caneta
andar -c/a
virar 90° para a esquerda     # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo Y+
baixar caneta
desenha a reta                # voltando ao ponto de partida da reta
subir caneta
virar 90° para a esquerda     # fico virado para o eixo X-
andar -c/a                    # retorna para a origem
virar 180° para a direita     # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
```

Em Python, sendo `t` a tartaruga:

```
t.penup()
t.forward(-c/a)
t.left(90)           # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo Y+
t.pendown()
# desenha a reta e volta a esse mesmo ponto
t.penup()
t.left(90)           # fico virado para o eixo X-
t.forward(-c/a)      # retorna para a origem
t.right(180)         # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
```

### Reta com inclinação

Representando a reta apenas por `(a,b,c)`, se `a != 0` e `b != 0`, então temos uma reta inclinada que varia tanto no eixo X quanto no eixo Y.

Eu sei que ela intercepta o eixo X quando `y = 0`, logo esse ponto é `(-c/a,0)`. Em seguida, devo determinar a direção da reta.

Quando a equação da reta está no formato `y = m*x + k`, então `m` vale a tangente do ângulo que a reta faz com o eixo X. Esse ângulo é a rotação do quanto no sentido anti-horário é necessário girar para que apontar na direção da reta. Então eu posso obter o ângulo em radianos via [`math.atan(m)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan). Como `m = -a/b`, então eu obtenho o ângulo via `math.atan(-a/b)`.

Eu também posso calcular o ângulo sem fazer essa divisão explícita através do [`math.atan2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2). Quando `x` varia `b` unidades, então `y` precisa variar `-a` unidades:

```
; seja (x0,y0) o ponto inicial da reta e (x1,y1) o ponto da reta obtida deslocando x0 em b unidades
a*x0 + b*y0 + c = 0
a*x1 + b*y1 + c = 0

x1 = x0 + b
; portanto:

a*(x0 + b) + b*y1 + c = 0
a*x0 + a*b + b*y1 + c = 0
a*x0 + a*b + b*y1 + c = a*x0 + b*y0 + c
a*b + b*y1 = b*y0
b*y1 = b*y0 - a*b = b*(y0 - a)
; como b != 0, pois a reta está inclinada:
y1 = y0 - a

; portanto, a inclinação é
(b, -a)
```

Como demonstrado, a direção da reta aponta para `(b, -a)`, chamar `math.atan2(-a, b)` retornaria o ângulo adequado para apontar nessa direção.

Após achar o ângulo em radianos, só transformar em graus e usar na tartaruga.

Em Python, abstraindo `radians2degree` que transforma radianos em graus, ficaria assim para desenhar a reta:

```
inclinacao = radians2degrees(math.atan2(-a, b))
t.penup()
t.forward(-c/a)      # vai ao ponto em que a reta corte o eixo X
t.left(inclinacao)   # inclina na direção da reta
t.pendown()
# desenha a reta e volta a esse mesmo ponto
t.penup()
t.right(inclinacao)  # fico virado para o eixo X+
t.left(180)          # viro para o eixo X-
t.forward(-c/a)      # retorna para a origem
t.right(180)         # volto a ficar voltado para o eixo X+
```

## Ponto específico de dificuldade

Estando em qualquer lugar da tela, eu consigo desenhar um segmento de tamanho arbitrário. É possível pegar as dimensões da tela em passos de tartaruga através das chamadas `t.window_height()` e `t.window_length()`. Eu sei que eu consigo desenhar ocupando a tela (com excedente) desenhando `(h**2 + w**2)**0.5` para frente, virando 180°, andando 2 vezes essa distância, depois virando 180° de novo e andando essa distância novamente para voltar à origem do desenho (é necessário rodar 180° para voltar à orientação original). Porém, esse método de desenho inclui um "desperdício" de desenho fora da tela.

> A distância `(h**2 + w**2)**0.5` é a maior possível entre dois pontos de uma janela retangular: a distância entre o ponto inferior-esquerdo e o superior-direito.

Atualmente, com uma constante de 50 para frente e para trás, eu desenho um pequeno segmento, não a reta inteira:

[image: desenho automatizado da reta obtida a partir da "subtração" da equação de duas circunferências]

No caso, eu estava propositadamente testando para obter a equação da reta a partir de circunferências cujos centros tem sempre `y = 0`, por isso as retas são todas verticais.

Comment: E qual é a dúvida? :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss desenhar com a tartaruga algo que seja "visualmente" uma reta na tela. Quando digo "visualmente uma reta" é indicando que, na área visual, o segmento desenhado vai até as bordas. Queria desenhar sem exceder até as bordas, excedendo no máximo apenas erro de arredondamento

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, a minha resposta te ajudou?

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quer ultrapassar o limite da tela, a opção mais simples seria fazer um loop em que a tartaruga anda pequenos passos enquanto não atinge a borda:

```
w = turtle.window_width()
h = turtle.window_height()
while abs(t.xcor())<w/2 and abs(t.ycor())<h/2:
    t.fd(5)
```

outra opção é calcular o tamanho do segmento até atingir a tela. Pro exemplo se `y=a*x+b` então o valor de x em que a tartaruga atinge a borda superior é `x_sup=(h/2-b)/a` e para a borda inferior é `x_inf=(-h/2-b)/a`. Assim sendo, o menor valor de x que a tartaruga pode ter é `min(x_sup,x_inf,-w/2)`, enquanto o maior valor é `max(x_sup,x_inf,w/2)`. Sabendo o maior e o menor valor de `x` que a tartaruga pode ter, calcule o valor de y com `y1 = a*x_max+b` e `y2 = a*x_max+b`. Nesse ponto, para determinar o quanto a sua tartaruga vai andar até atingir o limite basta fazer `d1 = math.sqrt((y1-b)**2+x_max**2)` e `d2 = math.sqrt((y2-b)**2+x_max**2)`. Termine com:

```
t.forward(d1)
t.left(180)
t.forward(d1+d2)
```

Aqui eu estou assumindo que sua tartaruga ja está em `(x,y)=(0,b)` e apontada para o ângulo certo e que você não quer usar `goto`